# How to improve the performance of Cassandra-Hector Java application

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I'm new to stack overflow and this is my first question, sorry if I made any mistake in presenting.

I'm new to big data and Cassandra. I'm given a task to analyse why a Rest call is taking more time to serve a Request. When I checked the code is fine and the time taken is for retrieving the response from the Cassandra Database. As I'm familiar with only RDBMS, can someone help me out how should I proceed to improve the performance, means how can I optimize the query.

What all are the things to be followed while querying a Cassandra Database?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Hi @Sva.Mu, below is one query : 'ColumnFamilyResult<Composite, Composite> result = queryColumns(
    param1, param2 );', then we are iterating the result. This is one query. Again we are populationg the pojo with 'Composite columnName : result.getColumnNames()'. So please advice me what things to be taken care to make sure we are not making redundant DB calls.